# Identify an iPhone uniquely in both cases: app and web app

Tags: iphone, mobile-website

Well, that's the question, i need to identify an iphone uniquely and detect it in both cases: web and app. In app case i can access to iphone id and in web i can use a cookie, but... is there anything i can use for both at the same time? i mean, can i use the web cookie also in the app or can i access to the iphone id from the web? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as identifying the client as the same user from the web and from the app, that's not possible. I can think of many top tier applications (Bank of America, Zillow, Yelp, Facebook, etc.) that don't have such feature.

Whomever is giving you this requirement is misinformed about such a capability on the iPhone. Punt it.

Comment: Lot of thanks Mike. I'll try something diferent to get the goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but, what about frameworks like PhoneGap, take a look at this url, it says you can get it! http://britg.com/2008/08/22/extending-phonegap-to-return-the-iphones-unique-identifier/

Comment: Looks like you should give it a try, and if it works, post it and accept it as your own answer.

Comment: as i've seen Phone Gap is used in Web APP's embebed in a native APP and not in a Safari's for web.

Comment: It's impossible then.. the philosophy of iPhone is that, absolutely isolated apps, and no access from Safari's webs to iPhone info, also impossible to comunicate between iPhone's app's, no cookies, no files, plists, no nothing, by the moment. And the politic they're trying is to put all this comunication in the cloud.